# How add file into p:fileUpload

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have `p:fileUpload` and i would like add file into `p:fileUpload` from managedbean.

Is it possible?

This my file upload:

```
<p:fileUpload id="idFile" value="#{n.uploadFileName}" skinSimple="true" mode="advanced"
fileUploadListener="#{n.uploadToInputSteam}" styleClass="inputField"/>
```

How can I set files in to FileUpload in managed bean?.

Comment: I have some problems trying to understand what you want achieve. Do you want to store the file in the file system of the server from within the managed bean? Do you want to make a previously uploaded file available for download?

Comment: Abihabi: given the way how you formulated the question, it looks like you were thrown in the deep JSF hole while not having the essential knowledge of basic HTML. I suggest you to take a step back and spend a bit more time learning basic HTML (and CSS and JS) before diving further deep with JSF. Start here: http://htmldog.com